# Button text color

Tags: html, css

I can't seems to put it together on my brain after almost practicing for 24 hours.I need help on changing the button text color to white, while the rest stay the same color

```css
//NAVIGATION
//========================

.nav ul
  display: flex
  padding-left: 0
  padding-top: 15px

.nav li
  list-style: none
  padding: 10px

.nav ul li a
  text-decoration: none
  color: #000000

.nav ul li:last-child
  color: #FFFFFF

.nav ul li a:hover
  color: #5c6ac4

.nav li:not(:last-child)
  margin-right: 20px

.nav li:nth-child(3)
  margin-right: auto

//BUTTON
//==============

.btn
  width: 160px
  height: 20px
  //border: 1px solid #5c6ac4
  background: #5c6ac4
  border-radius: 5px
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px

.btn:hover
  background: #212b35
  transition: background-color .6s ease-out
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Get started</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn">Hire me</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

[I've prepared an image on my particular issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qypAi.png)

Comment: Comments in CSS must be `/* comment */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already defined a color in `.nav ul li a`. You either need to overwrite that by adding `color: white !important` to `.btn` or change the structure of your code.

Handling a CSS file with many `!important` tags could become difficult in large projects, so try to avoid it.

Comment: Thx mate! The !important works, I take your advised to avoid. maybe along the way I'll try to see what's going and try to restructure it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Add `color: white;` to `.btn {..}` in css file (and comments in css are `/* comment */`:

```css
.btn {
  color: white;
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  /* border: 1px solid #5c6ac4; */
  background: #5c6ac4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}
```

Comment: I use SASS for my styling language. The comments are different.

Answer (score 0):

first you can't use preprocessor just like that, you should convert it to CSS and then use that CSS, and in CSS comments are `/*...*/` and rules are like `.btn{ key:value; }`

so after converting your sass to css we have :

```css
/* Navigation */
.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
.nav ul li:last-child {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #5c6ac4;
}
.nav li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.nav li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: auto;
}
/* Button */
.btn:hover {
  background: #212b35;
  transition: background-color .6s ease-out;
}

a.btn {
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  /*border: 1px solid #5c6ac4;*/
  background: #5c6ac4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get started</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn">Hire me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed, and why you did so?

Comment: @nullqube I use SASS for my styling language. I don't quite get the order of btn you trying to explain.

Comment: @jhpratt I don't get what you are trying to say. changed as in?

Comment: forget about it. the thing is you have to convert your sass to css before using it.

Comment: @nullqube Noted. Thanks for the advice appreciate much.